# Looping though/Accessing nested objects/array using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

So first time using React JS here and I am having some trouble.

I have an object which contains more objects and arrays and objects within objects etc.

I need to be able to access data from within the network object inside of the main parent object. I have tried many many ways and each result is just logging Object to the console instead of the actual contents of the object.

I have attached an image of the Main object structure.

I would appreciate any help.[image]

To get this object I am using xml2js:

```
xml2js.parseString(result.msg, function (err, result) {

                    console.log(result);

                });
```

One loop I tired was:

```
for(var p in result) {
                        if(result.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                            console.log('Object: ', p, ', Result: ', result[p], '\n');
                        }
                    }
```

that then returns:

[image]

Basically I need to access data within the parent object and display it in a table. So example i need to access the 'network' array which is within an object which is in the 'response' array.

using this code i was able to access the response object, but then I am not sure how to iterate over the arrays inside of this object.

```
xml2js.parseString(result.msg, function (err, result) {

                    console.log(result.wolterResponse['response']);

                    }

                });
```

[image]

Comment: You don't provide us enough information to help you. Could you give us some code to look at?

Comment: Hi, Apologies please see my edit. The problem is I do not have the code yet to loop/access the objects and arrays within the parent object.

Comment: I don't catch the difficulty of your issue with React since you will have the same issue in plain JS. Is your question is "how to give data to parent compoment" or something else ? I'm sorry but your question and description is hard to understand.

Comment: Hi, well i guess my issue isn't with react then.

basically i need to access data within the parent object and display it in a table. So example i need to access the 'network' array which is within an object which is in the 'response' array